# PyCUDA -- problems importing pycuda.driver

Tags: pycuda

- Windows 10
- Python 3.8
- CUDA 11.5

I've installed what I believe to be a matching pycuda from this file:
pycuda-2021.1+cuda115-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

This simple example fails

```
import pycuda.driver as drv

drv.init()

print("Detected {} CUDA devices".format(drv.Device.count()))
```

With this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/University of Arizona/weeds/tests/cuda-summary.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pycuda.driver as drv
  File "C:\Users\evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pycuda\driver.py", line 65, in <module>
    from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _driver: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

- NVCC is in my path
- Adding *os.add_dll_directory(os.path.join(os.environ['CUDA_PATH'], 'bin'))* has no effect

The script works just fine on my Jetson Nano

Any ideas on how to get past this?  I've searched and tried several solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite strange, but updating the Nvidia display driver fixed the issue for me.

But in my case there was no issue on my PC with the same versions of Windows, Python, CUDA and PyCuda. The issue appeared on the different Windows 10 machine, when launching the exe, packaged by PyInstaller. So, updating the display driver was the fix for this machine.